# How to convert index to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
xl_file
Out[19]: 
                  Day                     Description
Date                                                 
2011-01-26  Wednesday                    Republic Day
2011-03-02  Wednesday                   Mahashivratri
2011-04-12    Tuesday                       Ram Navmi
2011-04-14   Thursday  Dr. Babasaheb Ambedkar Jayanti
2011-04-22     Friday                     Good Friday
              ...                             ...
2020-05-25     Monday          Id-Ul-Fitr (Ramzan ID)
2020-10-02     Friday          Mahatma Gandhi Jayanti
2020-11-16     Monday            Diwali-Balipratipada
2020-11-30     Monday               Gurunanak Jayanti
2020-12-25     Friday                       Christmas

[144 rows x 2 columns]
```

How can i convert the `Date` index to `datetime` index?

I have tried `xl_file = pd.to_datetime(xl_file.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')`
This produces:

```
xl_file
Out[26]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-26', '2011-03-02', '2011-04-12', '2011-04-14',
               '2011-04-22', '2011-08-15', '2011-08-31', '2011-09-01',
               '2011-10-06', '2011-10-26',
               ...
               '2020-04-02', '2020-04-06', '2020-04-10', '2020-04-14',
               '2020-05-01', '2020-05-25', '2020-10-02', '2020-11-16',
               '2020-11-30', '2020-12-25'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=144, freq=None)
```

Why are all the other columns lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned the new index to the entire dataframe but you should assign it to its index:

```
xl_file.index = pd.to_datetime(xl_file.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```